# LINQ - Sequence contains no elements

Tags: linq

I am using a LINQ query as below.

```
object.collection.where(t => t.id.Equals("2")).First();
```

I am getting the error "Sequence contains no elements". Why does the result throw an error when the result contains no elements? Should it not return null when no results are found? That is what happens when using SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
object.collection.where(t => t.id.Equals("2")).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 16):

It's working as designed. The First() method is to be called when it's known at least one row will be returned. When this isn't the case, call FirstOrDefault().

Comment: The reason there are two First variants is to get specific exceptions to make debugging easier. Instead of a vague null reference exception, you get a more specific "sequence contains no elements".