# Sequence Contains No elements? Impossible to handle error?

Tags: javascript, c#, razor

I have the next JavaScript:

```
var document = 0;
if ('@Model.Article.ListFiles.First()' != null) {
document = '@Model.Article.ListFiles.First()';  }
```

`Article.ListFiles.First()` has Count values '0' for this test and of course I receive error

> "System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'"

but the problem is that I can't handle this error, I tried with `try/catch` but doesn't work. Also other operators `(!= null, != '', != '0', != 0)`

Comment: "_i tryed with try/catch_" where did you put them in c# code or js?

Comment: Try changing First to FirstOrDefault

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ - Sequence contains no elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647403/linq-sequence-contains-no-elements)

Comment: A note: your javascript `if` statement is trying to check if a **string** != **null**, which will *ALWAYS* be true, for whatever value you put inside the string.

Comment: What about `if ('@Model.Article.ListFiles.Any(f => f != null)' === 'True') {`

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable first, and check it aftetwards:

```
var a = '@Model.Article.ListFiles.First()';
var document = ''; 
if ( a !== null ) {
  document = a;
}
```

Comment: Well, it'll never be null either, since it's a server value wrapped in a string. It's always going to be a string.

Comment: Exactly what Heretic says (see my earlier comment under the question above). Also, you're **still** doing `.First()` on a possibly empty collection.

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem:

```
var document = '@Model.Article.ListFiles.FirstOrDefault()';
```

Thanks to all, special to asawyer!!!